# save list of data frames in a loop

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a list of data sets that I need to loop through and save the output. the names assigned belong to a character vector. For example:

```
list_data <- mtcars %>% group_split(cyl)

names_vector <- c("low", "medium", "high")

# this is what I am doing

low <- list_data[[1]]

medium <- list_data[[2]]

high <- list_data[[3]]
```

The names assigned belong to the character vector and it needs to be in order. the number of datasets in the list match the length of `names_vector`. but this needs to be iterated using a loop or some purr/dplyr functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop, you can rename the dataframes in a list using,

```
names(list_data) <- names_vector
```

Then separate each dataframes to environment,

```
list2env(list_data,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: `names(list_data) <- names_vector`

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of many questions. You can use `assign` or utilize the `%<-%` from the Zealot package.

```
library(zeallot)
c(low, medium, high) %<-% list_data
# Alternative:
names(list_data) <- c("low", "medium", "high")
mapply(list_data, names(list_data), FUN = \(x, name)assign(name, x, envir = globalenv()))
```